# Which one is correct? With a comma or without a comma

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

I was writing a sentence, and I later realized that this sentence might need punctuation. Which one would be the correct sentence: with a comma or without a comma

> Below are the topics we will be covering on Day-1.
>
> Below are the topics, we will be covering on Day-1.

I think a comma is required after "topics" because "Below are the topics" is a dependent clause and the next clause is independent.

Comment: If you keep the comma, you need to add *which* after it. (And the phrase after the comma is not independent; it could not stand on its own as a sentence.)

Comment: A restrictive relative clause (whether introduced by 'that', 'which', 'who'... or the zero relativiser) is not set off by a comma. So 'Below are the topics we will be covering on Day 1'  /  'Below are the topics that we will be covering on Day 1'  /  'Below are the topics which we will be covering on Day 1' //// A nonrestrictive clause cannot have a zero relativiser (so  'Below are topics A and B, which we will be covering on Day 1').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely without the comma. "The topics we will be covering on day 1" is all part of the same clause; "we will be covering on day 1" doesn't work on its own. If it was a separate clause you would use a comma; imagine something like "You can find the topics below, the course will be starting on day 1." (Though I'd probably prefer a semi colon in that example).

Comment: He dipped his feet in the lake, full of beautiful flowers" In this sentence, is there a need for a comma next to lake? "the lake that is full of beautiful flowers" is the implied meaning. Without the comma, the meaning seems to change here.